# Moodle foreign keys

Tags: database, foreign-key-relationship, moodle

i am installing moodle (2.2 or 2.5) and modified the sql generator.php to have foreign keys and map the database for studies proposes and i get this allways, i am using  5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server by the way

> Debug info: Table 'config' already exists CREATE TABLE config ( id
>   BIGINT(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET
>   utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', value LONGTEXT
>   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT
>   PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT
>   COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci Error code: ddlexecuteerror Stack trace:
>
> ```
> line 429 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: ddl_change_structure_exception thrown
> line 842 of \lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
> line 88 of \lib\ddl\database_manager.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->change_database_structure()
> line 77 of \lib\ddl\database_manager.php: call to database_manager->execute_sql()
> line 417 of \lib\ddl\database_manager.php: call to database_manager->execute_sql_arr()
> line 369 of \lib\ddl\database_manager.php: call to database_manager->install_from_xmldb_structure()
> line 1479 of \lib\upgradelib.php: call to database_manager->install_from_xmldb_file()
> line 203 of \admin\index.php: call to install_core()
> ```

i found this is a minor bug at https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-20437 anyways its for the version 1.9 but this is not the version i try to install

i have searched so far and no solution!. did someone actually fix this

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are naming your table "config" which is a big NO-NO. You are supposed to prefix your table names by the name of your module. E.g. if your module is called "mymodule", it's config table name should be "mymodule_config". I hope, this fixes it for you.

[See this Moodle dev wiki article for more information](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules#install.xml).